# Data properties dependency in Protege

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

Could someone please provide examples of what kind (if any) dependecies between Data Properties we can declare in Protege? 
Basically what I am trying to do is to declare simple rules, that e.g one Data Property (year) can or can not be before the other one ( like Birth Year <= Death Year). Is that possible to be done using Data Properties?

Comment: OWL doesn't have the concept of variables, but using SWRL rules is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The only dependencies that can be expressed between DataProperties are subproperty and disjointness properties. SWRLTab in Protege can be used to express rules. Assuming the following ontology:

```
ObjectProperty: hasDeathCertificate
  Domain: Person
  Range: DeathCertificate
DataProperty: dateOfBirth
  Domain: Person 
Range: xsd:dateTime
DataProperty: dateOfDeath
  Domain: DeathCertificate
  Range: xsd:dateTime
Class: DeathCertificate    
Class: Person
```

the following SWRL rule can be specified to ensure that the date of death on a DeathCertificate is after the date birth of the person.

```
Person(?p)^dateOfBirth(?p, ?birth)^DeathCertificate(?d)^dateOfDeath(?p, ?death)
^swrlb:greaterThan(?death, ?birth)->hasDeathCertificate(?p, ?d)
```

Good luck!